# git commit -am "Commit message" doesn't work properly with vagrant machine

Tags: windows, git, vagrant, hook, nfs

I am using Git Bash in Windows 7. For my project I installed VirtualBox and Vagrant on Windows. In my home directory there are some project folders which are synced into the vagrant machine based on nfs. So Vagrant will keep the files synchronous.

The box is a webserver based on debian/contrib-jessie64 with some configurations like Git for several packages to be installed via Composer. Git is for BitBucket purposes only because some packages need an ssh permission. But Git itself is never used by me within the box because it's very slow. Furthermore Git is required to listen to several hooks. The webserver does have PHP and Composer installed but my host machine (Windows) does not. The reason why I didn't install all the stuff on Windows is the circumstance to keep all versions the same on both host and guest machines. I do want the server do all the php stuff for me and that's fine.

So, working with Git on Windows requires git hooks to be configured on Windows as well as for the box. All the hooks, which are listening to changes on Windows, execute the corresponding hook within the vagrant box. All arguments are piped of course.

This is my pre-commit file on Windows

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
coreDirectory="$HOME/projects/foo"

arguments=""

for arg in "$@"
do
    arguments="$arguments $arg"
done

cd $coreDirectory && vagrant ssh -c "cd /home/projects/foo && 
./.git/hooks/pre-commit $arguments"
```

This works fine. The pre-commit file in the box is being executed and triggers a special Executor which calls the ./vendor/bin/phpcs file for code sniffing.

I only want to trigger the code sniffing rules on staged files, so all modified or untracked files which have been added to stage area should be sniffed. This also works fine. The Executor prepares all files with the following command:

```
git -C /home/projects/foo diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM --cached
```

In Windows adding desired files to staged area with **git add --all** and committing them works properly and the pre-commit hook triggers the pre-commit hook in the box which triggers the CodeSniffer.

But using **git commit -am "Foo bar"** does not work properly with the command above. The hook reacts but the Executor command within the machine, which tries to get the --cached files, returns an empty set.

I assume that either the vagrant box isn't fast enough to move the changed files to the staged area after I have used the **git commit -am** command on Windows or the command **git commit -am** doesn't even move files to staged area.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `git commit -a`, Git builds a *new and temporary* index to hold the files to be committed.  The existence of this new temporary index is communicated through an environment variable, `GIT_INDEX_FILE`.

When you use `ssh` to run commands on another machine (even though it's a VM, it's another machine for this purpose), that other machine does not receive the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` setting, so it uses the normal everyday index.  *That* index has no changes in it, so the behavior you are seeing is correct: in fact, nothing *is* staged.

Note that the contents of an index file differ on Windows and Linux (Git stores nearly-raw `stat` system call data), so it's generally unwise to attempt to share index files across hosts this way.  In fact, Virtualbox shared folders have a number of ... features? bugs? misfeatures? whatever you want to call them, *things* that fare poorly in Git environments.  I find it much more reliable to treat each VM as a truly separate machine, using the shared-folder feature as minimally as possible, and in particular never using it to store in-progress work with Git.

Comment: Hi torek. Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately the concept of Vagrant + Server-Puppet + Git in the machine and so on, is a guideline in this company I am working for. Some of our developers installed the CodeSniffer plugin on their PHPStorm IDE but I am a big fan of using the shell and there are others doing so as well.
So I need to solve this problem somehow. If there is no other possibility than using **git add .** before committing, than I have to communicate this rule to our developers.

Comment: You could try to copy the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable across the ssh session. See if your ssh supports `$HOME/.ssh/environment`.

Comment: So, do you mean, I need to export the variable in my hook files on Windows?
Like `export "GIT_INDEX_FILE=???"`

Comment: No, you would need to get whatever command it is that implements the ssh protocol to send an environment-setting request to the ssh server, and then need the ssh server to honor that request. Failing those two, you would need to write your own protocol system, and instead of using ssh to run Git directly, use ssh to run your communications program, or use your program instead of ssh (but the latter assumes you know how to write a secure shell, or are in a position in which security is not an issue).

Comment: I don't use Windows and do not know what capabilities its ssh client(s) have. This stuff is all built in to Unix/Linux ssh servers and clients, where it is tunable per server and client.

Comment: Ok thank you :) I will have to tell all coworkers that they have to stop **using commit -a** :D